# Simulation of sand particle collision

Tags: python, performance, simulation, pygame, collision

I am making a module that allows you to create sand and simulate it. I have successfully done this, but it runs very slowly. I need this to be able to simulate at least 1000 particles, at a fps higher than 5.
How do I optimize this code?

My code:

```py
import pygame, random, sys
pygame.init()
FPS = 60 
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Sand')

class SandSource:
    def __init__(self, screen, colliders):
        self.screen = screen
        self.tiles = colliders
        self.sand_arr = []
        self.colour = (255, 255, 0, 255)
        self.gradient = True
        self.gradients = []

    def update(self):
        for sand in self.sand_arr:
            sand1 = self.custom_sand_collision(sand)
            if self.gradient:
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, sand[2], sand1)
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, sand1)

    def check_pos_of(self, x, y):
        if self.screen.get_at((x, y)) in self.gradients:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def create_sand(self, x, y, sands=1):
        for i in range(sands):
            if self.gradient:
                COLOR = list(self.colour)
                COLOR[1] = COLOR[1] + random.randint(-50, 0)
                COLOR[0] = COLOR[0] + random.randint(-50, 0)
                COLOR = tuple(COLOR)
                if COLOR not in self.gradients:
                    self.gradients.append(COLOR)
                self.sand_arr.append([x, y, COLOR])
            else:
                self.sand_arr.append([x, y])

    def check_collide(self, x, y, rext):
        rext.x = x
        rext.y = y
        if self.collision_test(rext) or self.check_pos_of(x, y):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def custom_sand_collision(self, sand):
        ox = sand[0]
        oy = sand[1]
        vel = 4
        check = pygame.Rect((ox, oy), (1, 1))
        try:
            if self.collision_test(check):
                pass
            elif self.check_collide(ox, oy + 1, check):
                for i in range(vel):
                    if self.check_collide(ox, oy + i, check):
                        sand[1] = oy + i
            elif self.check_collide(ox - 1, oy + 1, check):
                sand[1] = oy + 1
                sand[0] -= 1
            elif self.check_collide(ox + 1, oy + 1, check):
                sand[1] += 1
                sand[0] += 1
        except:
            pass
        check.x = sand[0]
        check.y = sand[1]
        return check

    def collision_test(self, rect):
        for thing in self.tiles:
            if thing.colliderect(rect):
                return True
        return False

a = SandSource(screen, colliders=[pygame.Rect((0, 250), (300, 300))])
a.create_sand(100, 100, 1000)


while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    a.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Have you read about Numpy?

Comment: How would I use numpy to optimize this?

Comment: Read about vectorisation. Reinterpret your sand particles as being in a vector upon which operations need to be done on all of them at once.

Comment: I will look into it!

Comment: I am not sure if it supports pygame, but a quick way would be to try running the code with pypy instead of cpython.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't write, never commit/publish uncommented/undocumented code.
  Tell, in the code, what "everything" is there for.
  Python got it right specifying [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) such that it is easy to copy them with the code, and tedious to copy the code without them.
- just `return condition` (or `return bool(condition)` where not already boolean) instead of

  ```
  if condition:
      return True
  else:
      return False
  ```
- I find using `sand[1] = oy + 1` in one branch and `sand[1] += 1` in the next irritating.
  Coming to think of it, the "velocity branch" looks particularly peculiar, starting with checking the original location and continuing with a re-check of ox, oy + 1.

  - checking each abutting coordinate independently looks *brute force*.
- If `self.gradients` gets beyond small, using a set may reduce execution time.

Comment: This did help raise the framerate a little bit! Thanks.